# How to print return from Javascript into html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to javascript. My chrome extension currently is not printing text into the little window once the button is clicked.

The first bit is the popup.js and the second is popup.html.
My goal is force once you click the button, the area where it says filler is replaced with the text I have set in popup.js. I don't know javascript well and this is a lot of code that I have compiled from around. Thanks everyone!

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("click-this").addEventListener("click", handler;
});

// The handler also must go in a .js file
var date = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
function handler() {
  if (dayOfWeek == 0){
      return  "sunday";
  }
  else   if (dayOfWeek == 1){
        return  "monday";
    }
  else if (dayOfWeek == 2){
        return  "tuesday";
    }
  else if (dayOfWeek == 3){
        return  "wednesday";
    }
  else if (dayOfWeek == 4){
        return  "thursday";
    }
    else if (dayOfWeek == 5){
          return  "friday";
      }
      else if (dayOfWeek == 6){
            return  "saturday";
        }
       
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column large-6 medium-6 small-12">
        <h1> Lunch Menu </h1>
        <p> filler filler filler</p>
        <button type="button" id="click-this">Click</button>
    </div>
</div>

<style scoped>
  div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: If this question is answered please mark the appropriate answer as "answered". Welcome to SO!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Added id for the paragraph to change the value as per the output.Let me know if it works!!

```js
document.getElementById("click-this").addEventListener("click", function(){
var day;
switch (new Date().getDay()) 
{
case 0:
day = "Sunday";
break;
  case 1:
day = "Monday";
break;
  case 2:
day = "Tuesday";
break;
  case 3:
day = "Wednesday";
break;
  case 4:
day = "Thursday";
break;
  case 5:
day = "Friday";
break;
case  6:
  day = "Saturday";
}//end of switch case
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = day;
}//End of function
);
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column large-6 medium-6 small-12">
        <h1> Lunch Menu </h1>
        <p id="demo"> filler filler filler</p>
        <button type="button" id="click-this">Click</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<style scoped>
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;

}
</style>
```

Comment: @JoeyZhao Did my code work for your requirement or not?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to put closing brace before semicolon

```
document.getElementById("click-this").addEventListener("click", handler);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks haha. Unfortunately nothing happened :(.

Comment: @JoeyZhao What do you want to see exactly?

Comment: @JoeyZhao to see something you need to change all these **return  "tuesday";** to **window.alert("tuesday");** and you will see dialog box.

Comment: I want the filler text to be replaced with the text I choose, I put tuesday there right now but it will be changed later.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an editing program that has linter to check for any typing errors, it's really great when you're learning. My personal favorite is [Atom](https://atom.io/), although it's a bit heavy on RAM.

Comment: I am using atom. It doesn't correct it for some reason though.

Comment: Did you add a javascript linter package?